# JaNeLA reporting errors about valid JNLP

Tags: java, javafx-2, jnlp

I am using a tool called JaNeLA to check the JNLP file of my application.

My JNLP is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="http://myserver.com/downloads">
  <information>
    <title>My App</title>
    <vendor>My Vendor</vendor>
    <description>Application to do something</description>
    <homepage href="http://myserver.com/myapp" />
    <offline-allowed/>
    <shortcut online="true">
      <desktop/>
      <menu submenu="My App"/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>

  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>

  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7.0_25" java-vm-args="-Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"    href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <property name="myID" value="1" /> 
  </resources>

  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="my-app-0.0.1.jar" download="eager" />
  </resources>

  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <jar href="map-app-0.0.1.jar" download="eager" />
  </resources>

  <application-desc main-class="com.myApp.MyApp"/>

  <update check="always"/>

</jnlp>
```

It reports about:

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for file:/C:/Users/Desktop/myapp.jnlp

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'homepage'. One of '{description, icon, offline-allowed, shortcut, association, related-content}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'homepage'. One of '{description, icon, offline-allowed, shortcut, association, related-content}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'update'. No child element is expected at this point.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'update'. No child element is expected at this point.
XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8
Codebase + href 'http://myserver.com/C:/Users/Desktop/myapp.jnlp' is not equal to actual location of 'file:/C:/Users/Desktop/myapp.jnlp'.
Desktop icons were subject to bug nnnn in earlier J2SE versions
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'myapp-0.0.1.jar'.
The resource download at myapp-0.0.1.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at myapp-0.0.1.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the myapp-0.0.1.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for myapp-0.0.1.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'myapp-0.0.1.jar'.
The resource download at myapp-0.0.1.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at myapp-0.0.1.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the myapp-0.0.1.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for myapp-0.0.1.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

What I am not sure about is that JaNeLA reports about there being invalid content, i.e. `Invalid content was found starting with element 'homepage'. One of '{description, icon, offline-allowed, shortcut, association, related-content}' is expected.` This condition is met in the JNLP above.

Also, it reports about `Invalid content was found starting with element 'update'. No child element is expected at this point.` This condition is also met as per what I see.

Not sure why is it reporting (in red) about valid JNLP content. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you consult the [JaNeLA help](http://pscode.org/janela/help.html)?

Comment: Not much information..  (And patience wearing veeery thin..)

Comment: JaNeLA help says `Error (1)  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jar'. One of '{extension, property, package}' is expected.
This one fools a lot of people. It most often means that elements are out of the correct order in the launch file. Check the spelling, then try shifting the element further up the document.` In my case, the spelling are all correct and the order of the entries, i.e. description, shortcut, offline-allowed, all combinations tried. Please let me know if there is anything else that needs to be tried.

Comment: For the error: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'update'. No child element is expected at this point.` there is no help mentioned on the help page. Any pointers to get rid of this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JNLP puts the elements in the correct order.  Note that *both* elements were fixed by *shifting the element further up the document* - just as I suggested above.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="http://myserver.com/downloads">
  <information>
    <title>My App</title>
    <vendor>My Vendor</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://myserver.com/myapp" />
    <description>Application to do something</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
    <shortcut online="true">
      <desktop/>
      <menu submenu="My App"/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="always"/>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7.0_25" java-vm-args="-Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"    href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <property name="myID" value="1" /> 
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="my-app-0.0.1.jar" download="eager" />
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <jar href="map-app-0.0.1.jar" download="eager" />
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.myApp.MyApp"/>
</jnlp>
```

As to the other problem, change the JNLP, completely uninstall the current app. using the Java Control Panel, and load it up fresh.

Comment: Is the order of jnlp elements really important?

Comment: @SaeidNourian  Even if it it isn't, do you have an actual *reason* for putting the elements in a different order?

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson I'm just curious if you know of a known issues with cause webstart problems if elements are in wrong order? In your JaNeLA software it highlights wrong order as "red" which presumable means fatal error in jnlp file. If it's not a serious problem then why not color it green or yellow?

Comment: @SaeidNourian 1) The software gets warnings of 'element out of order' as XML errors from an API that validates against an XSD.  I have no intention of going through the elements returned as errors to try and distinguish between them.  2) *"why not color it green or yellow?"*  Why not **fix the damn thing?**  Your question sounds to me like "How do I get the compiler to ignore deprecation warnings?" - which should be fixed rather than ignored.  3) I've seen JNLP files fail for reasons *much more obscure* than 'elements out of order'.